# Functional tests for Flash

Tags: tools, selenium, functional, flash

We are using a rich client developed with Flex. We would like to build automated tests to test whole features. I saw a module for Selenium, Flex Monkium, which could do the job.

Did you try it out? Is it worth it? Do you know another solution?

Comment: In the spirit of Stack Exchange sites... did you try it out? :-)

Comment: Not yet, but I will. I'm mainly looking for alternatives I can try out too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We tried Flexmonkium and found that it was burdensome to get started and prone to versionitis. We've been dramatically more successful with [Flexpilot](http://www.flexpilot.org/). We use it with Selenium2 beta3 (WebDriver). The SauceLabs team is helping to move Flexpilot forward, whereas Flexmonkium didn't seem to be getting much contributor love.

Comment: Nice, I didn't kow Flexpilot. Seems great. I will look it. Thnak you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently trying FlexMonkium and while it seemed promising at first, the fact it only works with Selenium-1 is a kind of a turn off...

Here I am stuck again with the "unable to handle file upload dialog" problem that Selenium-2 finally solved. Have to go back to my old Sikuli/AutoIt workarounds.

Other than that, can't get it to work well without inserting sleep times in my scripts and hugly stuff like that.

As far as FlexMonkey goes, it wasn't working for me because as far as I can tell, it is only suited for unit testing and not standalone automated functional tests like I'm doing with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with [flexmonkey](http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey) about a year ago.  I was starting to make some progress, but ended up changing teams shortly after.  The person who took over didn't take it up, but it seems as though it could be promising.

Answer (score 1):

Please check related question
 - [Flex Test Automation Tools Questions](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/flex-test-automation-tools-questions)

FlexMonkey version 5 seems good. I was able to setup and try it out.