# Flex Test Automation Tools Questions

Tags: selenium, flash-selenium

Below tools I figured out for Flex Testing

- FlexMonkium - Selenium IDE Addon
- FlexMonkey - http://www.gorillalogic.com/flexmonkey
- FlexPilot - https://github.com/mde/flex-pilot/wiki
- FlexUISelenium - http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/

-> What would be most preferred tool from above list for developing flex based automation. Learning curve, Tool features

-> I have not found example blogpost for a flex based website testing :(, Any pointers to documentation/examples would be helpful

-> Any best practices / lessons if you have worked on this tool

Meantime, I'm beginning to start looking at FlexMonkey

---

Found a very good article. Wanted to share the same.

Selenium – Flex Integration Steps - 
http://vasu-teju.blogspot.com/2011/06/selenium-flex-integration-steps.html

Testing Flex Apps with FlexMonkey Reloaded
http://www.jamesward.com/2011/03/02/testing-flex-apps-with-flexmonkey-reloaded/

Many thanks to author - vasu for his time and effort to share knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some useful posts from Stack Overflow:

1. [please compare QTP, RIATest , Selenium for Flex Application Automation Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845640/please-compare-qtp-riatest-selenium-for-flex-application-automation-testing)
2. [Automated testing of FLEX based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462/automated-testing-of-flex-based-applications)
3. [Flex UI testing automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930678/flex-ui-testing-automation)
4. [Flex automated acceptance testing tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042150/flex-automated-acceptance-testing-tools)

Adobe Developer Connection also contains some tutorials on Flex testing tools. See for example this page: [Test and deploy Flex applications](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testing.html) There are tutorials on RIATest and FlexMonkey linked from that page.

Comment: Thanks, I found flexmonkey based on reads and blogs. Flex Automation is slightly different from other UI automation. Here the case is you need to compile your application with certain libraries for it to expose the id's as objects. This is something new for me.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am late but I have some practicals using sfapi.
https://github.com/jagdeepjain/selenium-flex-demo

Comment: It's too bad, this doesn't exactly answer the question but it isn't your fault. the question itself is not set up in such a way that it could be properly answered.