# FlexWebDriver does not work with YouTube under FireFox?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to make a script that plays all videos of YouTube channel and perform player settings and return status.

Execution of the following command does not create any error on java stacktrace but, neither has effect on YouTube player.

- `player.nextVideo()` (command does not move to next video),
- `player.previousVideo()` (command does not move to previous video), and
- `player.setShuffle(true)`.

Here is a complete script. My code use FlexWebDriver class, described for instance [here](http://www.blackpepper.co.uk/posts/driving-a-flex-application-via-selenium-2-webdriver/).

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Youtube {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    FlexWebDriver flashApp = new FlexWebDriver(driver, "movie_player");

    driver.get("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZUTMprV9dI&list=UUQc_OGfP0IsgOWT0vosmQjg&feature=plpp_play_all");
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    flashApp.call("nextVideo");
    flashApp.call("previousVideo");
    flashApp.call("setShuffle","true");
  }

}
```

Comment: As is, the code starts a FireFox browser and plays a series of YouTube videos.  I do not see any error messages. Can you explain what you mean by "perform player settings and give status"?  Where do you see the error messages?  In a Java stack trace?  In the browser?  Somewhere else?  Which version of Selenium are you  using?  Which version of FireFox?  Which operating system?  And finally, what is your question?

Comment: I don't get error in Java stack trace. Problem is that Effect of          flashApp.call("nextVideo"); /          flashApp.call("previousVideo"); /          flashApp.call("setShuffle","true"); commands are not appeared on youtube video player. when next video command execute next video should started on youtube player. but this is not happened

Comment: @Jasmine, I improved formatting a bit for you, so hopefully it can be better understood what your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because FirefoxDriver [does not support execution of Flex applications.](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4044)

Answer (score 4):

To test Flex applications you need to use a selenium flex testing framework. There are quite a few available such as [FlexUI](http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/). You can find out about others at this SQA question: [Further Detail On Flex Test Frameworks](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/flex-test-automation-tools-questions).